# How can I compare the values between the current and previous rows of a column by using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below set of data.

[image]

On this table, you can view per each employee a set of actions performed, the date that this action performed and a stage description (e.g Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3). Those data are sorted based on Employee, Date (from oldest to newest).

As you can see, employee with code '111'  has changed stage from 'stage 1' to 'change 2' on 20/01/2022.

I want to achieve the below outcome:

[image]

- Add two new columns 'FROM' and 'TO' that will display per each record the previous and next stage
- Add one new column 'Status', that displays per each record if changed stage or not
- Add one counter, that will count the number of actions needed per each employee for changing the stage. For example 5 actions needed for the employee with code '111' to change the stage. As you can, the counter will start counting from 1 for the same employee in order to calculate the actions that will be needed for changing to a new status.

I have tried the below solution for calculating the counter but without reaching the expected results.

```
import pandas as pd

data['Account-Stage'] = data['Employee Code'].map(str) + data['Stage'].map(str) 

data.sort_values(['Employee Code', 'Date'],
                 ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)

grouped = data.groupby('Account-Stage')
def rank(x): return x['Date'].rank(method='first').astype(int)
data["Counter"] = grouped.apply(rank).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Comment: you should use `df.rolling()` to achieve this...

Comment: Any help on this is much appreciated!